# Facebook API extend personal token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

I'm currently using facebook GraphApi (imported with facepy) to build a crawler that extracts information from a group that is not mine. Since facebook's API v2.5 doesn't support extracting information from a group that is not mine, I'm forced to used an older version. My question is, how can I extend my personal token lifetime, taking into account that I can't create an app because it forces me to use the most recent API version.  I'll drop the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import facebook
from facepy import GraphAPI
from facepy import get_extended_access_token
import json
import schedule
import time


group_id = "the group id" #grupo operações stop coimbra https://www.facebook.com/groups/operacaostopcoimbra/
access_token = "access token i took from facebook developers"



class Crawler():

    def __init__(self, access_token):
        self._access_token = access_token

    def crawl(self):
        graph = GraphAPI(self._access_token) #aceder à GraphAPI
        extended_token = get_extended_access_token(access_token, APP ID, APP SECRET) #PROBLEM IS HERE!
        print extended_token
        data = graph.get(group_id + "/feed", page=False, retry=3, limit=25)
        data = self._parseJson(data)
        return data


    def _parseJson(self, data):

        if data["data"][0]["message"]:
            return data["data"][0]["from"]["name"] + " " + data["data"][0]["from"]["id"] + " " + data["data"][0]["message"]
        else:
            return None



result = Crawler(access_token)
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(result.crawl())

while 1:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Did you manage to get around that and make it work?

Comment: Nope, we didn't manage to get around that, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like, no app, no token...